# Pages 09 4.0.3 wants an update

Tags: pages, upgrade

When I open Pages 09 4.0.3, it tells me I need a software update; yet, running Software Update responds that all software is up to date.

I believe there is a later version of Pages with improved Lion support (like full page modes).

I've been to Apple Support pages download section: No dice.

How can I get that upgrade?

Comment: Could you edit / tag this with the OS you are using? Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that the applications reside in /Applications/iWork '09 or the software update process does not seem to find them.

Comment: This has happened to me, too.

Comment: YAY, Kevin! I had taken all the apps out of the iWork folder to see them easier alphabetically. Once I put Pages, Numbers and Keynote in a folder with that name, Software Update saw them right away. Thank you.